# Opengl lighting not working

Tags: opengl, lighting, lwjgl

I have rendered a spinning model in LWJGL. I have calculated normals and enabled lighting. Now I make a light:

```
float lightpos[] = {0, 0, 0, 0}; 
FloatBuffer lightposb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(8);
lightposb.put(lightpos);
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightposb);
float light[] = {10, 10, 10, 1}; 
FloatBuffer lightb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(8);
lightb.put(light);
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightb);
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightb);
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightb);
```

The model, instead of being lit up, is a dark gray. Also, no color appears on the model, even though I set its color to cyan:

```
    float color[] = {0,1,1,1};
    FloatBuffer colorb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(8);
    colorb.put(color);
    glMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, colorb);
```

UPDATE: Even though I have calculated normals and set them with glNormal3f, the model still appears to be shaded flat.

UPDATE: I HAVE done glEnable(GL_LIGHTING) and glEnable(GL_LIGHT0); that is NOT the problem.

UPDATE: I reversed the order of the light code and the model code and now the model flashes white, then goes dark grey and stays there.

Comment: Hi, from your code I can see that lightning is not enabled in it. Try to put this line, glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); after "lightposb.put(lightpos);". Hope this will help you.

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: If it is a dark grey and not just black, then you only need to adjust the light settings. If it _is_ black, I cannot help because the code looks fine. Maybe you could include a little more for us?

Comment: This might do the trick,
glMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, colorb);
....... Use "glLoadIdentity();" after glLight...
Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Sid I have already done glMaterial (see above code) with no effect; glLoadIdentity makes the model dissapear.

Comment: @Justin The model is dark grey, not black; what settings do you suggest I change?

Comment: In that case, I usually find that the normals are not calculated properly or the light is not close enough. I would add some temporary controls to move the light around while the program is running and log the coordinates for you. If that does not work, I don't know what to tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding code from this example: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/66017-simple-lwjgl-lighting/

Comment: by using GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT or GL_SHININESS ?

Comment: @Sid by enabling color materials, and by changing the light position.

Answer (score 1):

What Sid said.

What you are missing is:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
```

Comment: I already did that earlier in my code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use both color and lighting you must activate openGL color materials using:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The model showing up as grey is a bi-product of lighting being enabled but no light actually being cast on the object aside from ambient.

Without seeing the where your object is being rendered it is possible that you are rendering within the object itself.

It is also possible that you missed enabling [color materials](http://math.hws.edu/graphicsnotes/c4/s2.html).

Also as a general helper with lighting you might want to [look through this](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/) to see if you missed anything.